# How to use hideDelay in Primefaces?

Tags: html, primefaces

Alright, I tried adding a hideDelay at the tooltip but there doesn't seem to have any effect on the Delay I tried copying from [here](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/tooltipOptions.jsf) the one with the hideDelay and it doesn't work.

```
<h:column id="opf1007_column_col01" 
    rendered="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.colbll01 ne null}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridHeaderText"
            value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.colbll01}"
            id="opf1007_gridheader_col01" 
            style="text-align:right;width:120px">
        </h:outputText>
    </f:facet>

    <p:inputText styleClass="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.inputClass}"
        id="opf1007_gridinput_col01"
        value="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.col01}" 
        style="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.style}color: #{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.col01 lt 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'};width:100px;text-align:right" 
        readonly="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.total_row}">
        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" minFractionDigits="0"/>
    </p:inputText>

    <p:commandButton ajax="false" type="submit" 
        styleClass="iconCommandButton"
        id="opf1007_command_col01" icon="ui-icon-search"
        action="#{pc_Opf1007.doOpf1007_command_listAction}" 
        style="width:14px;height:14px" 
        rendered="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.showIcon}">
        <f:param name="clicked_groupid"
            value="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.groupid}"></f:param>
        <f:param name="clicked_col_frdate"
            value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.col01_frdate}"></f:param> 
        <f:param name="clicked_col_todate"
            value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.col01_todate}"></f:param> 
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:tooltip for="opf1007_command_col01" hideDelay="500"  >  
        <div><h:outputLink id="lnk" value="http://www.primefaces.org" >
              <h:outputText value="#{msg.opf1007_tooltip_click}" />
             </h:outputLink></div>
    </p:tooltip>                                     
</h:column>
```

Comment: Does it work outside a column? Does it work when you use a specifc event? Does it fail in all browsers? Does it work in newer versions of PrimeFaces? Any javascript errors? Is the corresponding jacascript called?

Comment: Oh and that showcase is OLD,  check the real PF showcase and documentation